# Tool like SourceTree or similar to work on remote server trough SSH

Tags: git, ssh, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

i'm searching for a tool like SourceTree, but that can connect trough SSH to a remote server like VSCode with SSH.

To ask for a solution ill try to explain better the situation:

I come from a company where we were working on local and utilising SourceTree to manage branches, merges and all usual GIT procedure with attlassian tickets.
Now, i joined a startup that is shifting from a R&D to a prod, and they asked me to setup the GIT structure, tools and enviroment to be able to manage and optimize the developlment.
As a developer, and not expert in this field, i can understand what i need but im having hard time finidng a solution.
Now we connect in SSH to remote server, develop the feature needed, and commit and pushit to main with VSC source control. But i like it more visual like SourceTree and other, one suggested that we can develop and test on remote server, then run some rsync script and commit from local pc. But i can imagine that i can find better tools for this setup.

In recap, i would like to: from local pc, have a source control tool that is visually appealing, and easy to use like SourceTree, connected with the local's owner account to a remote server to see modified file, so i can work on VisualStudio in SSH remote server, develop and test. And then commit from my local machine.

I know it is confusing but hopefully i explained myself.

I tried to work with VSCode SSH but is not easy enough to understand branches and visually applealing for entry-level developer.

Or SourceTree i cannot find a solution to connect to a remote machine.

Or Rsync the data from the remote machine to local to be able to commit from local account.

Comment: A workaround is to edit files and commit them on the local machine with the help of SourceTree. Push the updated branches to a repository on the remote machine where you can switch revisions and run the code.

Comment: You can just enable X forwarding over SSH and then use `gitk` and `git gui` so long as you have a local X server (or you can VNC into a remote X server to get all the bells & whistles, including graphical 3-way mergetool)